# Read JSON array from a text file in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read a text file with a JSON array in it.
Can someone help me to find my mistake?

```
   ["io", {"in": 8, "out": 0, "dev": "68", "time": 1532035082.614868}]
   ["io", {"in": 0, "out": 0, "dev": "68", "time": 1532035082.97122}]
   ["test", {"A": [{"para1":[], "para2": true, "para3": 68, "name":"", "observation":[[2,3],[3,2]],"time": 1532035082.97122}]}]
```

I did not manage to have it run with

```
  import gzip
  with gzip.open('myfile', 'rb') as f
      json_data = jsonload(f)
  print(json_data)
```

I have an error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 278)`
I can see that my file is not a JSON file but represents a JSON array
I manage to have it work with pandas but I'd like to find out how to do it without pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json('myfile', lines=True)
print(data.head())
```

Answer (score 2):

`data = [json.loads(e) for e in f if e.strip()]`

[Example of usage](https://tio.run/##lVCxSgQxFOz3Kx6v2oWw7CbeGg@uuNLKwjKkiFxOI14SkncHcvjt64toJRZ2M495M8Pkd3pJUa1rOOVUCEIS8FpT7LoKO0DEDgAMhoQCrhgibkELwHQmRhOjg78wwkWzACmcPLN5o@SkNpOW4zLf6EV/2N82039s7m5nKX9cyFf68tmzyFwxu@Jm3BrLrw1LPlM5@2@qmC6tdHTNFltCeqq@XByFxFWMkUJZYZSQ1oq/0zm/DdLlEiL1ps00viV3qL0f4JgKeAiRFxwfiRXP9w99HSAcwY@VD7kf7LCunw)

Answer (score 0):

The data in your text file is not a valid JSON. These are actually three JSON files one after another.

You have at last two options for fixing it:

- put all the JSON to a single one, for example by making a list at the top of the structure
- read your file line by line and load JSONs separately

Comment: So what I shall do?

Comment: I've updated my answer with two suggestions.

Comment: Hi @Robson,
I did option 1.

   with open.('myfile', 'rb') as f:
       lines=f.readlines()

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 options:

option1: pandas

```
pd.read_json(filepath,compression='infer', orient='records, lines=True)
```

option 2: read line by line

```
with gzip.open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
     lines=f.readlines()
     data = [json.loads(l) for l in lines]
print(data)
```

Option 1 is fastest:

option 1 = 0.31 s

option 2 = 0.42 s